# VS Code change indentation setting for all files in codebase

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code provides an action panel to change the indentation settings

[image]

I change it from `Spaces: 2` to `Spaces: 4`. However, when I click on a different file, it goes back to `Spaces: 2`, forcing me to manually go through every file in my codebase an click the setting.

I would expect there to be a way to apply this system-wide. Is there?

Comment: use setting `editor.tabSize`

Comment: @rioV8 Ah, I already had that set, but didn't notice the part about `Editor: Detect Indentation` overriding it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Press F1 > `Preferences: Open Settings (UI)`

[image]

### 2. Set `Editor.tabSize` to desired value

[image]

### 3. Disable `Editor.detectIndentation`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson):

```json
"editor.tabSize": 4
```

The setting's description:

> The number of spaces a tab is equal to. This setting is overridden based on the file contents when `#editor.detectIndentation#` is on.

---

You may also find it useful to add the following:

```json
"editor.detectIndentation": false
```

The setting's description:

> Controls whether `#editor.tabSize#` and `#editor.insertSpaces#` will be automatically detected when a file is opened based on the file contents.